# TextView wrap text after changing typeface

Tags: android, textview

I have this problem:

[image]
[image]

Well, the words in the article are ClickableSpans that change color and typeface on click. Because of BOLD being a bit wider, some text at the end of the line moves out of the screen. Though one can scroll it sideways, I'd still like the cut- or hidden- words move to next line.

Is this possible? I have tried `invalidate()`, resetting textview width again, but nothing helped me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a few workouts to your problem.

Try any one of these attributes on your `TextView`:

- `android:layout_weight=1`
- `android:width="0dip"`
- `android:ellipsize="none"`
- `android:scrollHorizontally="false"`

For your scroll view,you could try:

```
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/SCROLL_VIEW"  
android:layout_height="fill_parent"   
android:layout_width="fill_parent">  

<TextView   
   android:id="@+id/TEXT_VIEW"   
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"   
   android:text="Here goes your text" />  
</ScrollView>
```

Now within the TextView parameters, try and add one of the attributes mentioned above. Since you need wrapping after changing typeface, I'm not sure as to which attribute will fit your need.

Comment: The textview is wrapped by a scroll view, so how should I set up the scrollview? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Reflowing text on clicking a link is not a good idea from the user experience point of view. So you should consider changing just the color and not the typeface of the text.

If you still want to go ahead with this, you can call `requestLayout()` followed by `invalidate()` on the textview.

Comment: doesn't work, but youre right, it's a bad design idea. Downsizing the bold word would probably not hurt that much, or not using bold at all...

Comment: see if calling requestLayout and invalidate helps. Thats what they do in the TextView's source code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `TextView` inside of the `Layout`, hard code the `layout_width` with `dip` in `Layout` tag and use the `layout_weight=1` to your `TextView` tag.

**Note:** The above process can only be implemented if your application can be used in Portrait Mode.

Answer (score 0):

One more thing you can try is call `textView.requestLayout()`